# Ruby objects/method/attr_accessor use

Tags: ruby

Take an example. I have a class `Worktype` with a function `add(id, name)`

Worktype has different users. 
Now, if `w1` is the object of `Worktype`, I need to do something like this `w1.user.add(id, name)`

I was suggested to declare user as `attr_accessor` to access this method but that leads to undefined method `add`.

How can this be done?

Comment: What is the class of a `user`?

Comment: Is this a Ruby question, or a Ruby on Rails question? You mention models in the comments to sawa's answer.

Comment: This is a ruby question, not Ruby on Rails, I mentioned models because I am using DataMapper.

Answer (score 0):

From your description `w1.user.add(id, name)`, it looks like you want to define `add` method within whatever the class that `name` belongs to. It should not be a method in `Worktype`.

Comment: But name and id are just the parameters being passed. Can I use user to access any methods of the Class Worktype?

Comment: No you cannot, unless the `user` has the information of which `worktype` it belongs to.

Comment: Sorry, I am a Ruby noob.
How can I define methods for attr_accessors?

Comment: Everything is ruby is an object, meaning that it belongs to some class, and all the methods should be defined for that class. As I wrote above, define the methods on the class that `name` belongs to. I asked a question in the comment above. Answer that.

Comment: Worktype and user are both classes are actually models where one  worktype has n users.